# Как svg элементу растянуть задний фон?

Tags: html, css, svg

есть такая форма

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

                <defs>
                    <pattern id="image" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">
                      <image x="0" y="0"  width="100" height="100" xlink:href="1111111.jpg"></image>
                    </pattern>
                </defs>

                <path fill="url(#image)" d="M64.6,-24.3C72.3,2.6,59.1,32.9,38.5,46.4C17.8,59.9,-10.4,56.5,-29.7,42.2C-49,27.9,-59.4,2.6,-53,-22.6C-46.6,-47.7,-23.3,-72.7,2.6,-73.6C28.5,-74.4,57,-51.1,64.6,-24.3Z" transform="translate(100 100)"/>
            </svg>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но задний фон не получается растянуть, сама картинка 1920x1080, может есть что-то вроде background-size: 100%; ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Замените [patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/patternUnits) на `patternUnits = "objectBoundingBox"`
Задайте ширину и высоту в процентах

```
 <pattern id="image"  width="100%" height="100%">
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

                <defs>
                    <pattern id="image" patternUnits = "objectBoundingBox"  width="100%" height="100%">
                      <image x="-20" y="0"  width="75%" height="75%" xlink:href="http://i.imgur.com/3DWAbmN.jpg"></image>
                    </pattern>
                </defs>

                <path fill="url(#image)"  d="M64.6,-24.3C72.3,2.6,59.1,32.9,38.5,46.4C17.8,59.9,-10.4,56.5,-29.7,42.2C-49,27.9,-59.4,2.6,-53,-22.6C-46.6,-47.7,-23.3,-72.7,2.6,-73.6C28.5,-74.4,57,-51.1,64.6,-24.3Z" transform="translate(100 100)"/>
            </svg>
```

Дополнительные возможности позиционирования и масштабирования, можно получить при оборачивании svg в контейнер

```
<div class="container">
   <svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  ....
   </svg>
</div>
```

В этом случае блок svg может занимать весь контейнер и быть

### С фиксированными размерами

```css
.container {
width:200px;
height:200px;
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

                <defs>
                    <pattern id="image" patternUnits = "objectBoundingBox" width="100%" height="100%">
                      <image x="-20" y="0"  width="75%" height="75%" xlink:href="http://i.imgur.com/3DWAbmN.jpg"></image>
                    </pattern>
                </defs>

                <path fill="url(#image)"  d="M64.6,-24.3C72.3,2.6,59.1,32.9,38.5,46.4C17.8,59.9,-10.4,56.5,-29.7,42.2C-49,27.9,-59.4,2.6,-53,-22.6C-46.6,-47.7,-23.3,-72.7,2.6,-73.6C28.5,-74.4,57,-51.1,64.6,-24.3Z" transform="translate(100 100)"/>
            </svg>
</div>
```

### C масштабированием в зависимости от размеров дисплея гаджета

```css
.container {
width:45%;
height:45%;
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

                <defs>
                    <pattern id="image" patternUnits = "objectBoundingBox" width="100%" height="100%">
                      <image x="-20" y="0"  width="75%" height="75%" xlink:href="http://i.imgur.com/3DWAbmN.jpg"></image>
                    </pattern>
                </defs>

                <path fill="url(#image)"  d="M64.6,-24.3C72.3,2.6,59.1,32.9,38.5,46.4C17.8,59.9,-10.4,56.5,-29.7,42.2C-49,27.9,-59.4,2.6,-53,-22.6C-46.6,-47.7,-23.3,-72.7,2.6,-73.6C28.5,-74.4,57,-51.1,64.6,-24.3Z" transform="translate(100 100)"/>
            </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, огромное спасибо за ответ, а можно вас попросить еще помочь с background-attachment: fixed;? Идея в том, чтобы изображение внутри при скролле тоже двигалось снизу вверх, это можно реализовать?

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос, примите этот ответ и сформулируйте новый вопрос

Comment: хорошо, спасибо

Comment: а в примерах `patternUnits = "objectBoundingBox"` нигде не используется

Comment: @Grundy objectBoundingBox значение по умолчанию, можно не писать, см. ссылку на MDN в ответе. Сейчас добавлю objectBoundingBox и всё останется также

Comment: стоило это добавить в ответ, а то получилось: используйте это - и в примерах не используется :)

Comment: @Grundy Ты конечно прав, твой вопрос вполне законен. Спасибо